# Put value of application.properties in annotation @GetMapping

Tags: java, spring-boot, get-mapping

I'm tried to call a get http response with spring boot, and I have a value of url in application.properties, I'm tried to call this value in annotation @GetMapping like that :

```
@GetMapping("${service.url}")
```

But Spring boot says  **"Cannot resolve @PathVariable service.url"**

Maybe there are another way to get this value ?

Thanks for your help everyone.

Comment: I might be wrong, but IMHO those values can be only either raw string value or a constant

Answer (score 1):

Try using [SpEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html). In your case, this can be modelled as something like

```
@GetMapping("#{'${service.url}'}")
```

Comment: Thanks but it's the same , Cannot resolve @PathVariable service.url"

How can I do with a constant variable ?

Comment: That is just a warning from your IDE though. The application should still be working as expected although your IDE is just telling you that your URI has a `Path Variable` which you are not resolving/reading in your method definition. Any specific reason for reading the path URI from the properties file?

Answer (score 0):

In your `Controller` class, you can pass an object of type `org.springframework.core.env.Environment` in the constructor, e.g. named env.

Then you can just call

```
@GetMapping("${env.getRequiredProperty("service.url")}")
```